# Alternate for Indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing

We need result from Table based on datetime filter. But it working slow in mysql. I can't implement indexing on date & timestamp columns due to it will slow our insertion/updation. So can you please suggest any alternate for select the data quickly based on date and datetime filter with better performance.

SQL Query :

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     (
          SELECT  id
                  , title
                  , language
                  , lang_code
                  , financial
                  , fname
                  , lname
                  , mname
                  , mname_br
                  , suffix
                  , CASE WHEN DOB='0000-00-00' THEN NULL ELSE DOB END AS DOB
                  , street
                  , street2
                  , postal_code
                  , zip_ext
                  , city
                  , state
                  , country_code
                  , phone_home
                  , phone_biz
                  , phone_biz_ext
                  , phone_contact
                  , phone_cell
                  , status
                  , CASE WHEN date='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE
                    CAST(date as datetime) END AS date
                  , sex
                  , referrer
                  , referrerID
                  , providerID
                  , ethnoracial
                  , pid
                  , temp_key
                  , primary_care
                  , default_facility
                  , created_by
                  , patientStatus
                  , primary_care_id
                  , Sec_HCFA
                  , noBalanceBill
                  , erx_entry
                  , erx_patient_id
                  , athenaID
                  , CASE WHEN licenseDate='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE  licenseDate end as licenseDate
                  , race
                  , otherRace
                  , ethnicity
                  , otherEthnicity
                  , primary_care_phy_name
                  , primary_care_phy_id
                  , CASE WHEN dod_patient='0000-00-00' THEN NULL ELSE dod_patient END AS dod_patient-- 
                  , locked-- 
                  , co_man_phy-- 
                  , co_man_phy_id-- 
                  , vip-- 
                  , External_MRN_1-- 
                  , External_MRN_2-- 
                  , External_MRN_3-- 
                  , External_MRN_4
                  , as_id
                  , CASE WHEN acc_statement_date='0000-00-00' THEN acc_statement_date END AS acc_statement_date
                  , CASE WHEN timestamp='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE timestamp END AS timestamp
                  , api_id
                  , fmh_pt_status
                  , race_code
                  , ethnicity_code
                  , patient_payer
                  , CASE WHEN date='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE date END AS transfer_created
                  ,CASE  WHEN timestamp='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE timestamp END AS transfer_updated
                  ,CASE  WHEN date > '2020-11-10 00:00:00' THEN 'new' ELSE 'changed' END AS flagfield
                  ,CASE  WHEN date='0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE date END AS sortdate
          FROM patient_data
          WHERE (date > '2020-11-10 00:00:00' or timestamp > '2019-04-01 19:53:57-04')
          AND month(date) > 0)t
          ORDER BY flagfield desc,
                  sortdate;
         )
```

id Column has indexing in the table

Comment: *" I can't implement indexing on date & timestamp columns due to it will slow our insertion/updation."* this overhead is minimal when in doubt insert/update multiple qeuries in a transaction  *"So can you please suggest any alternate for select the data quickly based on date and datetime filter with better performance."* No indexes are the only way..

Comment: Now i think of it you could deploy [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) as it can run without indexes and "optimize" (read skip unmatched partitions) (SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE) queries with [Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html) .. And using subpartitions also might help to separate the table data into year - month tables for example.. **But keep in mind there are [restrictions and limitations on using partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html)**

Comment: `I can't implement indexing on date & timestamp columns due to it will slow our insertion/updation` - this is entirely false. If the query above is slow, it means you didn't configure your MySQL at all so it runs with default config - which is designed so that MySQL runs on computers from 2001. Index your fields, configure MySQL so OS can allocate sufficient resources to it and simply use the right tool for the job. In your case, an index is the right tool. There's no way you *"can't"* use it. Did you even measure if your inserts slow down because of indexes?

Comment: @Mjh No, I haven't see performance of insert or update after implementing index on date & timestamp column. But as per my knowledge i assumed it will definitely slow it. Because we are inserting approx 300 times per day. As you have mentioned used the right tool, can you please suggest any tool. Or please confirm implementing index on date column will not effect our application performance.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes we can do partitioning, but it will again slow down the Table performance in terms of inserting or updation. Please confirm m i right

Comment: *"Table performance in terms of inserting or updation. Please confirm m i right"* again this overhead is minimal and most likely faster then updating indexes, also yes MySQL needs to calculate where the select/insert/update should happen in which  partition table file.. In thoery using partitioning should be able to do this (much) faster then a "single" table file which holds millions or billions or records.

Comment: 300 times a day? If you were to insert 300 times per SECOND, you wouldn't notice notable slowdowns on today's hardware. Index your fields, measure. Your assumption is, luckily for you, wrong so you can get out of this problem the easiest way possible - by adding indexes.

Comment: What is `month(date) > 0` supposed to catch??

Comment: What is the `-04` in `'2019-04-01 19:53:57-04'`?

Comment: "indexing on date & timestamp columns due to it will slow our insertion/updation" -- Really?  How many rows per second are you inserting/updating?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I won't have to discuss `TEXT`, `UNION`, etc in hypothetical terms.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
         )t
```

it adds nothing, except to slow things down.

Let's focus on

```
  SELECT id
      FROM patient_data
      WHERE (date > '2020-11-10 00:00:00'
           or timestamp > '2019-04-01 19:53:57-04')
      AND month(date) > 0
```

Does that shortened query run "too slow"?  If not, then we can use that as a derived table to see if that will speed it up.  If so, then we will need to get into `UNION` and indexing.